# swipe tag, actionBar error

Tags: android, scrollbar, swipe

I'm creating swipe tab , its crushes
Can you help

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        actionBar=getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Java").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("PHP").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(".Net").setTabListener(this));

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

the error is:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a null pointer error occurring, you should check the result of getActionBar() to make sure its not returning null. Check it below

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (getActionBar() != null){
            actionBar=getActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode( ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText( "Java").setTabListener(this));
            actionBar.addTab( actionBar.newTab().setText("PHP").setTabListener(this));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab() .setText(".Net").setTabListener(this));
        }
    }
    //your initialization continues
}
```

It shouldnt give a null pointer exception again. But you have to check your XML layout to make sure there an actionbar in the activity xml file